# How to setup Jest tests for Vuetify3 (Vue3 + TypeScript)?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

The project requires my team to use Jest (instead of Vitest). We are using Vuetify3 (Vue3) and TypeScript. There is a lot of documentation for Vue2 & Jest setups, but not for Vue3. Vuetify themselves only offer a tutorial for Vitest (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/unit-testing/).

We tried a bunch of different things, but always come to this error message in our test files for components that use Vuetify components (plain HTML elements are fine!):

```bash
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      2 | import { describe, expect } from '@jest/globals';
      3 | import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils"
    > 4 | import { createVuetify } from "vuetify"
```

The test file looks like this (testing a component that includes a Vuetify `v-dialog` and `v-btn`):

```js
import { describe, expect } from '@jest/globals';
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils"
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify"
import * as components from "vuetify/components"
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives"
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue"

describe("MyComponent.vue", () => {
    it('renders correctly', () => {
        const vuetify = createVuetify({
            components,
            directives
        })
        const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
            global: {
                plugins: [
                    vuetify
                ]
            }
        })
        expect(wrapper.find(`[data-testid="myTestId"]`).exists()).toBe(true)
    })
})
```

Our `jest.config.js` looks like this:

```js
export default {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.vue$": '@vue/vue3-jest',
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(js|ts)$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['vue', 'js', 'ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/testHelper/__mocks__/styleMock.ts",
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  },
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    customExportConditions: ["node", "node-addons"],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!vuetify)'
  ],
}
```

We even configured a `babel.config.json` because it was suggested plenty of times on StackOverlow:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

`package.json` excerpt:

```json
{
"type": "module",
 ...
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/types": "^7.21.4",
    "@jest/globals": "^29.7.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
    "@types/babel__core": "^7",
    "@types/babel__preset-env": "^7",
    "@types/eslint": "^8",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.3",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^29.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "core-js": "^3.29.0",
    "eslint": "^8.54.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.18.1",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.0",
    "vite": "^4.2.0",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.3.9",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^3.4.4"
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! If you need more details, don't hestitate to ask.

Comment: to fix error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` just add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`

Comment: @Vasyl I already did that. It doesn't change anything. Any other idea?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have no idea.
(Well, if there is an issue caused by Vuetify, you can try to patch it and fix locally, but the root cause is still to be identified)